# "Rick was to ... taken.". Should it be "be" or "have"?

Tags: grammar

On my last english exam there was a question to fill in the gaps. One of the sentences to complete was "Rick was to ... taken.". What would you put in here and why? I think there should be "have", but some of my friends say "be". Would that sentence mean anything when filled with "be"?

Comment: "Rick was to ... taken." is the whole sentence.

Comment: In that case, *be* is almost certainly intended, but it's still unnatural as a standalone sentence. If you could [edit] your post to explain why you think *have* is preferable to *be*, given all the meanings of *[take](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/take_1)*, however, that should be good enough to draw an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the five words (including the answer) in `Rick was to _____ taken.` was meant to be a complete, grammatically correct sentence, I believe the answer has to be "*be*".  That would give you:

> Rick was to *be* taken.

Meaning that, for example, rather than getting to the ceremony on his own, someone else would get him there -- Rick was to be taken [instead of driving himself.]

The word "*have*", however, could fit if it were a sentence fragment (i.e., not a complete sentence.)  Consider this scenario:

> We knew the aliens would be collecting another specimen.  We knew who that had to be: Rick was to ***be*** taken.  Unfortunately, we got our timing wrong.  Rick was to ***have*** taken anti-alien-probe meds but they beamed him up before he could do so.  Poor Rick.

On its own, however, "*Rick was to **have** taken*" is incomplete; the verb *taken*, in this situation, needs an object -- he was to have taken *what?*  So, given that it was meant to be complete, "*have*" doesn't fit.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The correct one would be "Rick was to **be** taken"

Comment: Why is that the right answer?  Because it sounds right in your head? Please cite your reasoning.

Comment: The correct answer depends on context.  You should explain the context that you have assumed in your answer.